# How to move multiple UV's face together to the 2D cursor

Tags: uv

[image]

I want to move all of those rectangles to be stacked on the 2D cursor, because I want to reuse a texture area for all those UVs.

- Manually dragging : not accurate, no snapping
- Align X/Y : The rectangle collapse into a little dot
- Shift + S -> snap to cursor (offset) : They are not gathered/stacked together, they retain the original spacing
- Selecting one by one and do snap to cursor (offset) : Works but time consuming, is there any operator that do this for all items?

Comment: Look into UV Align/Distribute addon, it should be able to stack UV islands, though as I tried before 2D cursor aligning doesn't work as expected (maybe was bug)

Answer (score 1):

One (not perfect, but useful) workaround: select all faces that will share the same portion of the texture and press U choosing "reset" option: all thoose faces will be UV unwrapped in a stack covering all the UV space available. This "big square" can be scaled and moved to the right place and dimensions with a single shot, even using the "Shift S, selected to cursor" option.